# When Is It Apt to Convert Features to Log-values Before Fitting

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, anomaly-detection

I am planning to implement anomaly detection using **one-class SVM**. The data which I have has 25 features and some of the columns have unique variations like trend and seasonality.

I have tried to convert the trend and seasonal features into log-values. I have found that the distribution has changed from skewed to normal.

I am not certain, though, if the convertion is way-to-go. Also, I am not sure what consequences it may cause during the fitting.

It would be greatly appreciated if anybody could highlight the best case scenario of converting the features into log-values and/or any other techniques which could mitigate the effect of time series variations.

Comment: To understand the effect you should fit `SVM` and verify the results with the preferred metrics **twice**: with the raw data and the converted data. There is no solid answer whether you should tinker with interpolation (i.e. convertion into log-values). `One-class SVM` still deals with the classification problem and not a regression problem. You may read more about time series variations and how to deal with them [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/02/time-series-forecasting-codes-python/)

Comment: Ok. Thank you. @E.Z.